# Usage of "yet" and "as yet"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 1- ***As yet*** it is not known whether the crash was the result of an
>   accident. ([Original](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-yet))
>
> 2- ***Yet*** it is not known whether the crash was the result of an
>   accident.

---

> 3- The report remains unfinished ***as of yet***. ([Original](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/as-of-yet))
>
> 4- The report remains unfinished ***yet***.

In these sentences above, can I use "***as (of) yet***" instead of "***yet***" as in 2 and 4 ?

---

I have one more question: A dictionary says "as yet" implies a meaning "said thing will definitely be changed" Is that always true?

> [Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/yet): ***As yet*** means ‘up to now, but the situation
>   ***will definitely change***’. We only use it in negative contexts.

And gives example :

> The film shows you the most typical places, ***as yet untouched by
>   tourism***, and how to get there.

Comment: Hi Talha. You may want to take a look at [What are tags and how do I use them?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) in the [help]. It’s better to use existing tags than to create new ones. Tags group questions together, and help people find questions on topics that interest them. If there is only one question with a particular tag, it doesn’t work well.

Comment: Related question: [Are “as of yet”, “as yet” and “yet” all synonymous?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/196697/9161)

Answer (score 1):

"As of yet" does not exist as an English expression. It seems to be a blend of "as yet" and "as of now". (I would not say "as of now" in any context, but many people do).

"As yet" means "so far", "up to now".

"Yet" can also mean "so far", "up to now" in some contexts, but cannot stand first in a clause with this meaning, because in that position another meaning "even so" or "even if" takes precedence.

So your 1) is normal. Your 2) is grammatical, but has quite a different meaning.

3) I would call ungrammatical.

4) is grammatical, but not idiomatic, but I'm not completely sure why not. I think it is because *yet* (in that sense) requires an explicit negator, not the implicit one in "unfinished". So

> *The report isn't finished yet.* is idiomatic, but
>
> *The report is unfinished yet.* is not idiomatic, for me. I would say "so far", or "as yet".

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain the meaning of sentence 2 ? This version seems okay to me : It is not known whether the crash was the result of an accident yet. (+ This sentence uses explicit negator- is not.)

Comment: Sentence 2 means "Even so, it is not known ... ". It expresses that, though whatever came before might lead you to think that it would be known, it is not. There is no expression of time in it. Your sentence in your comment is find, @TalhaÖzden

Comment: Thank you. Would you use "The report is unfinished as yet. " or "The report is as yet unfinished." ?

Comment: Either, @TalhaÖzden

Comment: Hi, I saw this sentence " but nobody ***yet*** knows what the real population question will be like.... Can I use "as yet" here? As in: "but ***as yet*** nobody knows what the real population question will be like." or "but nobody ***as yet*** knows what the real population question will be like." (Source: https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/shaw/works/guide3.htm)

Comment: @TalhaÖzden: I find _but nobody as yet knows_ to be grammatical, but not idiomatic. _But as yet nobody knows_ **is** idiomatic, for the same reason as your original 1) is better than 2): _yet_ would have a different meaning from _as yet_ there.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought "as yet" would be better than "yet" in the absence of explicit negator. Isn't this one- "but as yet nobody knows what the real population question will be like."- more idiomatic than the original one I quoted?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden: no, I think they're equally idiomatic. The form with _as yet_ puts more emphasis on the _as yet_: it suggests that there is an expectation that somebody soon will know, whereas the form with just _yet_ does not suggest that, or not so strongly.